# Call JQuery function through Web API Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I went through many posts but none exactly targeted a Web API Controller in the MVC Framework so I had to write a post regarding this.

I am using C# and my controller action looks something like this:

```
//[HttpGet]/[HttpPost]/etc.. anything can be here
    public IEnumerable<something> Customers()
    {
     //Code
        return List;
    }
```

And my script in my cshtml view file looks something like below:

```
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
}
```

Now if I want to call a jquery function and/or pass some data to it as well on the client side from my C# code, what would my action and jquery code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MVC controller should look like similar to this...

```
public class ExampleController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Customers(string nameParameter)
    {
        //Code
        return Json(nameParameter);
    }
}
```

You need to define the accepted parameters in the functions constructor.

Your Ajax call on the other hand...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Example/Customers?nameParameter=Asbah",
  success: function(html){
    // Returned value
  }
});
```

The parameters need to match the names you defined in your function constructor. Note in the URL /Example/ it refers to ExampleController.